# How to add a list of clicked items to an input field and be able to retrieve them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment I am clicking on country regions and I adding their propriety name to an input field, i am doing this as I need to send the input value to backend. This is I could be clicking many countries, so this is what I currently do for one single country:

```
<input type="text" id="usp-custom-3">

function zoomToFeature(e) {
        this.getElement().classList.toggle('active');
        var name = e.target.feature.properties.name;
        jQuery("#usp-custom-3").val(name);
  }

  function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
      click: zoomToFeature
    });
  }
```

With `this.getElement().classList.toggle('active');` I mean when I click on a country polygon. As i said I might be clicking more than one country, so how to add more than one country name in the `input` like "Italy France Spain" and be able to remove them if we click again on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep an array and show that?

```
var selected=[];
function zoomToFeature(e) {
    this.getElement().classList.toggle('active');
    var name=e.target.feature.properties.name;
    var i;
    if((i=selected.indexOf(name))+1){//check if existing
       selected.splice(i,1);//remove
    }else{
       selected.push(name);//add
    }
    jQuery("#usp-custom-3").val(selected.join("<br>"));//show with each being in a new row
 }

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
layer.on({
  click: zoomToFeature
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```js
const i = document.querySelector('input');

const els = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for (const el of els) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const v = i.value.split(' '); // get countries inside input value
    if (!v.includes(el.textContent)) { // if not already in the input field
     i.value = v.concat(el.textContent).join(' '); // add a new text
    } else {
     i.value = v.filter(text => text !== el.textContent).join(' '); // remove if already there
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Italy</p>
  <p>Spain</p>
  <p>Germany</p>
</div>

<input type="text">
```

Comment: we won't be able to remove the elements if we click again on them